# Cordova + Vue.js : Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode

Tags: android, cordova, vue.js

I'm buiding mobile app using Cordova + Vue.js

I'm facing this issue :***Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode***

When building for **browser** (cordova build browser + cordova run browser), it works perfectly as expected

When building for **Android** (cordova build android + cordova run android), build is sucessfull but when I launch it on my device, Vue components are not displayed at all (there are no errors in the app).
However, HTML tags like < p > are correctly displayed.

When inspecting with Chrome Devtools, I'm facing this in the error log : 
**bundle.js:4917 Uncaught SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode**

Bundle.js is an auto generated file so I should not modify it

Node version : v10.3.0

npm version : 6.1.0

Device Android Version : 5.0.1

If someone can help me, don't hesitate